# Required a audio format baby crying data set

Tags: data-request, audio

For my undergraduate research project, I'm trying to train my system with infant child crying frequencies and predict the reason for a new baby crying sound. I'm following this [journal](http://iiav.org/archives_icsv_last/2015_icsv22/content/papers/papers/full_paper_361_20150302104000311.pdf)  and they are using 78 different crying sounds manually collected from 31 babies by paediatricians. I'm trying to train the system in five different categories:

1. HUNGRY
2. SLEEP
3. PAIN
4. NEED TO BURP
5. UNCOMFORTABLE

for now, I'm working with very little [data](http://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/crying-baby.html#1) collected online.
I'm looking for a good dataset for more than 4 months. The dataset should have more than 50 data with labels (the categories I mentioned above ). If anyone knows a good source please help me out with this hurdle. Looking for a public dataset. but even a paid version won't be a problem.

Comment: Have you considered obtaining the data yourself by asking expecting parents and parents of newborns to help? Since their volunteer effort would be to improve the lives of babies everywhere (including possibly their own second child), you might get some takers.

Comment: i'm working on almost the same thing. Have you found a reliable database?

Comment: @Biruntha Gnaneswaran : Can you update your journal link, it seems to be broken as of now, would be helpful as I'm working on the same thing currently

Answer (score 5):

[donateacry-corpus repository](https://github.com/gveres/donateacry-corpus)  is an infant cry audio corpus that's being built through the Donate-a-cry campaign.
It doesn't look maintained and the campaign itself appears dead, but the data remains!

[Free Sounds Search for "baby"](http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=baby) returns over 1500 answers; not all are what you seek, but on the first page of results, 6/10 look like they fit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

The [DCASE2017 challenge, task: Rare Sound Event Detection](https://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/dcase2017/challenge/task-rare-sound-event-detection)  has a dataset which contains baby cry (as well as glass breaking and gunshot). The target sounds were collected from the FreeSound database.